# How stack memory works when pushing value to it on x86_64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, stack-memory, stack-pointer

I have been writing some code in assembly and i found a bug that was overwriting others memory locations and giving to me a segmentation fault, this trouble was made using the rbp register, but the following example use other register to make easy to understand.

```
 ; Moving some value to rax and pushing to stack
 mov rax, "romulomo"
 push rax

 ; Moving rbp to same location of rsp that points to "romulomo"
 mov rbp, rsp

 ; Moving a debug byte to position rbp-1
 mov BYTE [rbp-1], "#"

 ; Printing everything
 mov rax, 1
 mov rdi, 1
 lea rsi, [rbp]
 mov rdx, 8
 syscall

 ; Exit from program
 mov rax, 60
 syscall
```

My questions is: Using the fact that stack increase down, the rbp is pointing to the first byte of sequence (0) or the last byte of sequence (7) on the data pushed using rax register ?

[image]

The output of program is:

```
romulomo
```

It isn't weird? i put a '#' where should be the first 'o' of 'romulo' and the program prints exactly 'romulomo'.

Something interesting is that if i put the '#' using rbp+1 like in the following example, this works without any troubles, however, doing it, theoretically i put before the entire sequence of bytes...

```
mov BYTE [rbp+1], "#"
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You put a `#` before the `r`.  Push does `rsp-=8` and a store, so after a push of that constant, `byte [rsp]` holds `'r'`.  And `[rsp-1]` is the byte before that.  In a debugger like GDB, examine stack memory, like `x /16cx $rsp-8`.  (Or copy/paste a numeric address so you can dump from a consistent reference point even while RSP moves.)

Comment: Remember that unlike C, assembly does not implicitly scale your pointer arithmetic. In other words, when you `push rax` the CPU subtracts 8 from `rsp`, not 1. So when you do `mov byte [rbp+1], "#"` you're overwriting the last "o" in "romulomo", not the lowest byte of the return address like you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that `RSP` point to the address : 0xFF1E8

```
 ; Moving some value to rax and pushing to stack
 mov rax, "romulomo" 
 push rax 

;                                      +-> RSP=0xFF1E98-8
;Low              stack                |         High
;+-------------------------------------+--------+
;|                                     |romulomo| 
;+-------------------------------------+--------+
; RSP=0xFF1E90 | RBP=0xXXXXXXX
 

; Moving rbp to same location of rsp that points to "romulomo"
 mov rbp, rsp

; RSP=0xFF1E90 | RBP=0xFF1E90
 
; Moving a debug byte to position rbp-1
 mov BYTE [rbp-1], "#"

;                                       +-> RBP = RSP = 0xFF1E90
;Low              stack           |RBP-1|         High
;+--------------------------------+-----+--------+
;|                                |  #  |romulomo| 
;+--------------------------------+-----+--------+
; RSP=0xFF1E90 | RBP=0xFF1E90

; mov BYTE [rbp+1], "#" ; to replace the first "o" with "#": r#mulomo

;                                         
;Low              stack           |RBP-1|RBP|RBP+1|      RBP+8
;+--------------------------------+-----+---+-----+------+
;|                                |  #  | r |  o  |mulomo| 
;+--------------------------------+-----+---+-----+------+


 ; Printing everything
 mov rax, 1          ; __NR_write
 mov rdi, 1          ; fd = stdout

 lea rsi, [rbp]      ; mov rsi, rbp  would be more efficient
;            RSI = start of buffer = RBP = RSP = 0xFF1E90
;Low              stack           |RBP-1|         High
;+--------------------------------+-----+--------+
;|                                |  #  |romulomo| 
;+--------------------------------+-----+--------+

 mov rdx, 8          ; length = 8 bytes
 syscall             ; write(1, rsi, 8)

 ; Exit from program
 mov rax, 60
 syscall
```

Comment: RSP should always be 8-byte aligned, so it's an odd choice of example.  Also, the code in the question only did one 8-byte `push rax`, so if there's a `'\0'` character after the 8-byte `romulomo`, that's just coincidence and not part of the data this question is working with.  Your example seems to be showing it as a 9-byte push?  x86-64 registers are 64-bit, not 72.  Otherwise yeah that looks right, good diagrams. Should be easy to fix them to remove the `\0` part and change the starting address to `0xFF1E98` so RSP after `push` is still `0xFF1E90`.